# ASP.NET MVC & Angular: Unable to get property 'id' of undefined or null reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, controller

I am having issues displaying my database with an Angular application. The Controller and all other necessary classes for the entity and API were done in Visual Studio. I have tested the API and it works.

I am getting the following message in the Console: "Unable to get property 'id' of undefined or null reference", which tells me that I am not getting the Controller code to communicate with the Angular application correctly. If someone could help steer me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it, as I am quite new to this. Thank You:

```
// In the Repository
public async Task<List<TestTableTburns>> GetAllAsync()
 {
     var query = "SELECT Id, Name, CreateDate FROM TestTableTburns";

     using (var conn = _connectionFactory.Create())
     {
         try
         {
             var testTableTburns = await conn.QueryAsync<TestTableTburns>(query);

             return testTableTburns.ToList();
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(e);
             throw;
         }
     }
 }






// API call in the Controller, routes to api/test-table-tburns
 /// <summary>
 /// Gets data from test entity
 /// </summary>
 /// <response code="200">Data from test entity</response> 
 [HttpGet]
 [Route("api/test-table-tburns")]
 [ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(List<TestTableTburnsModel>))]
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
 {
     try
     {
         IList results =
             (await _testTableTburnsRepository.GetAllAsync())
             .Select(_ => new TestTableTburnsModel { Id = _.Id, Name = _.Name, CreateDate = _.CreateDate }).ToList();

         return Ok(results);
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         return StatusCode(500, e);
     }
 }
```

Comment: It looks like you’re trying to call a property (Id) of an object that is not existing. Can you add the code, where this happens?

Comment: Here is code I've written in Visual Studio: https://codepaste.net/95wt8i

Comment: Where does the error occur in the API (c#) or the app (Chrome, whatever)?

Comment: It occurs in the app, using Internet Explorer.

Comment: Did you try to debug it in the browser?

Comment: Can you add the .js/.cshtml file, where the api/Controller is requested?

Comment: @Nikolaus: Error I'm getting in the console: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (TestTableTburnsListComponent.html:10)

Comment: @Nikolaus:
TestTableTburnsListComponent is specifically pointing to this code, the 'id' line: https://codepaste.net/kwktr0

If I remove the Id then the error moves down to Name.

If I put `test-table-tburns?.Id`, it shows 'NaN' in the location of where the data should be. Viewing the Network tab I can preview the data elements of my table and they show up fine, it just seems that they aren't displaying.

Comment: Can you add your response-data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually not very familiar with typescript (which seems to be the way you are handling angular). However, from the code you provided, the html template does not have a controller. You have a model, which is your object. You have a service to handle the model data, and you have what you call 'component', which looks like a controller for me.

Nevertheless, even though you generate your page using the 'component' and the html template provided, your html template does not have the tag "ng-controller". In angular you must specify which portion of your code will be able to access a controller's data, to do so, you must use the "ng-controller" tag, in your case, inside the first  would do the trick.

If you are already aware of this already and the way of handling Angular in typescript do not need to indicate a controller with the tag "ng-controller", please forget everything I said though. I'd like to know more about it =)

Comment: I actually had that piece of code in there before, however, it was not working. I put in the Controller class from Visual Studio in the div tags. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Angular needs you to have a an app, inside that app you are allowed to stablish controllers. Using sample code you could create a div like <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">{{variableToPrint}}</div>. Inside your controller js file, you will need to indicate that the app you are using is "myApp" and instantiate myApp somewhere before the controller definition. Here follows an example: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_controllers.asp

Answer (score 0):

I haven't run your code but my guess is that your http json response is not matching with the data type you are trying to parse into. As per you code your api response should look something like this

```
{
  "Id": '123',
  "Name": "Name",
  "CreatedDate": "2011-07-14T19:43:37+0100"
}
```

So as you see your TestTableTburnsModel has the property in lower case and json keys are in Sentence case (First letter capital). So try matching them like

```
export class TestTableTburnsModel{
Id: string;
Name: string;
CreateDate: string;
}
```

PS. I know that as per javascript naming convention first letter should be small. But to match it with json you have keep them similar

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried this and I am still getting the same error.